# Excel: If, Search and match data from 3 different tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to search and match data from 3 different tables which are connected through an id and if the outcome is 1 of 5 options, then it is Yes or NO

see picture below for example. the yellow column should be filled it. the picture shows what the result should be.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just some nested `INDEX` & `MATCH` could work for you:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(K$3:K$7,MATCH(INDEX(H$3:H$7,MATCH(INDEX(E$3:E$7,MATCH("*"&A3&"*",D$3:D$7,0)),G$3:G$7,0)),J$3:J$7,0)),"")
```

`MATCH` allows the use of a wildcard ***and*** is at least as fast as `VLOOKUP` would be but usually faster!

Comment: your formula works great. but it is a bit more difficult to change it since I have to embed the 5 options in my formula. can you help me with that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe you could insert another `MATCH` and `INDEX`? @Sapman.

Comment: in your formula you index and match column J and column K.  since in my excel file there is no column J and K, i want to embed in the formula something like `=IF("Option 1";"Yes";IF("Option 2";"NO"))` etc

Comment: Hm, something like: `=IFERROR(INDEX({"Yes","Yes","Yes","No","No"},MATCH(INDEX(H$3:H$7,MATCH(INDEX(E$3:E$7,MATCH("*"&A3&"*",D$3:D$7,0)),G$3:G$7,0)),{"Option 1","Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5"},0)),"")`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help this works perfect. can you explain why the options have to be between `{}` brackets? I got stuck there.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

[image]

Here's the code if you want to copy/paste & try it out:

```
=IF(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP("*"&A3&"*", $D$3:$E$7, 2,FALSE), $G$3:$H$7, 2, FALSE) < 4, "Yes", "No")
```

I guess the biggest difference is that it will say "N/A" instead of "Empty" when there is no match.

Comment: Yup nice, that's the `VLOOKUP` equivalent =)

Comment: in your screenshot it seems to work, but when I use it it shows No or #N/A even when it should be Yes. Furthermore your formula works based on numbers in my sample options. In my actual file the options don't have any numbers in it and I have to embed them in formula. But your formula helped me to understand how I can create a similar formula, so thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Sapman.
Here's my suggestion to your particular case:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP(IF(MIN(IF((LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D$2:$D$6,A2,""))-LEN($D$2:$D$6))<>0,ROW($D$2:$D$6)-1))=0,"",INDEX($E$2:$E$6,MIN(IF((LEN(SUBSTITUTE($D$2:$D$6,A2,""))-LEN($D$2:$D$6))<>0,ROW($D$2:$D$6)-2)))),$G$2:$H$6,2,FALSE),$J$3:$K$7,2,FALSE),"EMPTY")
```

It is based on the following logic:

- first we take a value from Table A and remove it from Table B
- then we check the length of the resulting string, if it's now different (i.e. LEN(XXACA)=5, LEN(XX)=2)
- if it's different, we return the ROW number minus 2 (as your tables have two header rows)
- then we use INDEX/MATCH to return the value of that row in Table B
- then we do VLOOKUP twice to get data from Table C and Table "If/Then"

There are several error-handling parts as well which esure that you get the result you requested.

Comment: the formula doesn't fully work when there the search criteria is in the middel or end of the name. For example for ACA it returns Empty because there is XX infront of it in D5. For AAB it works since D4 starts with AAB.